# Python 2d array get all rows where first column is equal to 0

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, list, numpy, image-processing

As you see in the 2d array there are multiple rgb values, I want to get all the rows which first column is equal to zero, so in this case

**output: [[  0 115 700], [  0 115 701], [  0 115 702]]**

```
[[  0 115 700]
 [  0 115 701]
 [  0 115 702]
  ..., 
 [  1 978 445]
 [  1 978 446]
 [  1 978 447]]
```

Comment: That isn't valid syntax. Post what your list actually looks like

Comment: those are really big numpy array can't post here if you can give me logic or expalin with an example that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

assuming you array name is `data`

```
data[data[:,0]==0]
```